# Configuring IPTABLES for Passive FTP Connection through NAT (Forwarding from One PC to Another Using a Second Ethernet Card)

Tags: iptables, firewall, ftp, nat

I am trying to connect to an FTP server through a NAT network created by another PC that uses two Ethernet cards. I would like to access via FTP client the second PC's FTP server through the first one. The hardware configuration is as follows:
[image]

The FTP server can be reached via standard port 21, while I use the 1024-1048 port range for passive connection. On the local network without NAT, the FTP server works perfectly. While when I enter NAT rules with iptables I can connect to port 21 but not get the list of files and folders.The iptables configuration I am using is as follows:

```
*filter   
-A FORWARD -d 145.34.67.230/32 -i enp1s0 -o enp2s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT  
-A FORWARD -d 145.34.67.230/32 -i enp1s0 -o enp2s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1024:1048 -j ACCEPT 
COMMIT  
*nat  
-A PREROUTING -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j DNAT --to-destination 145.34.67.230:21  
-A PREROUTING -i enp1s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1024:1048 -j DNAT --to-destination 145.34.67.230:1024-1048  
COMMIT
```

I scanned the network with wireshark while trying to connect and found that the FTP server sends the address and port relative to the local network as you can see:

[image]

I would like to figure out what I need to set to correct the packets coming in from the FTP server so that my FTP client can properly connect through the NAT.

I am using a regular Ubuntu 22.04.

Thanks for the help

Comment: check this: https://home.regit.org/netfilter-en/secure-use-of-helpers/ (note what was optional before has become mandatory today).

Comment: Anyway, I don't understand why you would have the client not contact directly the server which has a public IP address. With PASV this would have worked without additional care. So you'll have to explain first why this use case (to avoid an answer missing the problem).

Comment: I don't understand why *anyone* is still using FTP.